# Chrome Browser crashing if .assert.containsText fails in nightwatch

Tags: nightwatch.js

Very recently we are seeing chrome browser crashing , when ever my '.assert.containsText' fails. This was not happening before.

Can you help me resolve this issue?

S/W details :

Nightwatch version : 0.9.20
Chrome Driver : 2.41.0
Selenium Server :3.14.0

Answer (score 1):

Adding this piece of code under the nightwatch.local.conf.js has fixed the issue.

```
test_settings: {
    default: {
        end_session_on_fail: false,
    }
```